# Cannot publish lambda message to RabbitMQ from AWS Lambda, connection timeout

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, rabbitmq, amqp

I am try to publish message to RabbitMQ from AWS lambda, but it not work.

I have a instance of RabbitMQ from AWS MQ, wish have a public access (user and password only) like below.

[image]

The producer is an AWS Lambda with nodejs, triggered from HTTP endpoint, the class that connects with RabbitMQ looks like below.

[image]

When I run the code on localhost it works fine, but when deployed to AWS Lambda the connection to RabbitMQ returns timeout.

I already made sure that the connection is correct.

endPoint: amqps://my-resource.amazonaws.com:my-port.

user: my-user.

passwork: my-passwork.

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the error? There might be variety of reasons for the failure.

Comment: @Parachute  it doesn't give any error, it just keeps trying to connect to timeout. Task timed out after 20.04 seconds

Comment: Make sure Lambda has outbound traffic enable to access Amazon MQ port